# How to pass value from python to html form using flask/jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

So I first create an array of all folders in a specific directory, I then pass that to my html file.

```
def test_yt_vid():
mylist = os.listdir(WD+r"static/"+YOUTUBE_FOLDER)
full_path = (WD+YOUTUBE_FOLDER)
return dict(mylist=mylist, full_path=full_path)
```

Next I look through that array to find what file has been selected.

```
<select name=list id="videolist" method="GET" action="/">
        {% for mylist in mylist %}
            <option value= "{{mylist}}" SELECTED>{{mylist}}</option>"
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Next I use JS to get the specific value into a variable

```
$('#videolist').change(function () {
//console.log($("#videolist").val());
 var fileInput = $("#videolist").val())};
```

So The problem is here, I'm not sure how I would go about passing that value into the following jinja code

```
<video id="videotesting1" class="video" width="300" height="240" autoplay loop controls="true">
<source src="{{url_for('static',filename='videoTest/' + 'testVid.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
</video >
```

I'm trying to replace 'testVid.mp4' with the variable fileInput from the JS, I tried using `$("#videotesting1").attr("src","{{url_for('static',filename='videoTest/'" + fileInput +")}}");'`

But no luck so far.

This is different to "How do you change video src using jQuery?" because I am trying to pass a jinja variable to HTML using js.

Comment: What troubles do you have? Any errors? Log messages?

Comment: GET :8080/static/videoTest/%20+%20fileInput%20+:1 GET http://192.168.2.97:8080/static/videoTest/%20+%20fileInput%20+ net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: Which is the value of fileInput? It seems that is setting the variable name as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out the problem, the file name has to go outside the jinja code because it doesnt get rendered by jinja for some reason when the event happens.

```
$("#videotesting1").attr("src","{{url_for('static',filename='videoTest/')}}" + fileInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some wrong closed quotes. Take a look at filename, where you set `'videoTest/'` plus some variable value (e.g `x`), which results in `'videoTest/'x`. Do you notice it? The single quote closed after `videoTest` should appear after the variable `fileInput`. The correct way would be:

```
$("#videotesting1").attr("src","{{url_for('static',filename='videoTest/" + fileInput + "')}}");
```

---

When you modify the src, has by *inspect element* the src changed, but the desired video isn't being played? If so, try:

```
$("#videotesting1").load()
```

Take a look at what [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) does @ JQuery docs.

Comment: thanks I tried this, but its didn't seem to do anything.